# Form action WordPress Plugin

Tags: php, html, wordpress, multisite

I am creating a specialized WordPress plugin, and its not for use outside of this singular case for the rest of the question we will refer to the wordpress plugin folder as plug-folder. Inside the plug-folder I have multiple files, a file named form_submit.php and a file named form_template.php. form_template.php is registered as a page template that can be applied to any post or page through the WordPress dashboard. The issue is because the form_submit.php file is inside the plugin folder how do I map my form action to post the data to the file? Simply listing it as

```
<form action="form_submit.php" method="post" >
```

Will not work as I need because it will be looking for the form_submit.php in the root directory of the site not the plugin folder and trying to map out the URL scheme for it in the plugin folder like

```
<form action="wp-content/plugins/plug-folder/form_submit.php" method="post" >
```

Doesn't work either, does a method exist that I am not thinking of?

Edit: After switching to use plugins_url() as suggested its working in one of the two instances where I am using forms. My register form (attached below) is not working, comes back error loading page.

```
<form action="<?php echo plugins_url( 'register_submit.php', __FILE__ ); ?>" method="post" autocomplete="off">

                            <?php if($_GET['error'] == 'username'){ ?>
                                <div class="error_message">
                                    Uh oh! That username is already taken.
                                </div>
                            <?php }else if($_GET['error'] == 'email'){ ?>
                                <div class="error_message">
                                    Uh oh! That email is already in use.
                                </div>
                            <?php }else if($_GET['error'] == 'email_invalid'){ ?>
                                <div class="error_message">
                                    Uh oh! Make sure to enter a valid email.
                                </div>
                            <?php }else if($_GET['error'] == 'signup_blank'){ ?>
                                <div class="error_message">
                                    Uh oh! Make sure to fill in all the fields.
                                </div>
                            <?php } ?>


                            <input type="text" name="first_name" class="signup_input" id="first_name_input" placeholder="First Name" value="<?= $_GET['first_name']; ?>" required>

                            <input type="text" name="last_name" class="signup_input" id="last_name_input" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?= $_GET['last_name']; ?>" required>

                            <input type="text" name="email" class="signup_input" placeholder="Email" value="<?= $_GET['email']; ?>" required>

                            <input type="password" name="password" class="signup_input" placeholder="Password" required>

                            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" required> <font color="#FFF">Female</font> &nbsp;
                            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" required> <font color="#FFF">Male </font>

                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Sign Up" style="margin-left: 15px;">

</form>
```

But my login form works.

```
                    <form action="<?php echo plugins_url( 'login_submit.php', __FILE__ ); ?>" method="post" autocomplete="off">

                      <div class="list-block">
                        <ul>
                                <span class="ti-user"></span>
                                <div class="item-input">
                                    <input type="text" name="email"  placeholder="E-Mail">
                                </div>
                            <div class="item-content margin-top-15">
                                <span class="ti-lock"></span>
                                <div class="item-input">
                                    <input type="password" name="password"  placeholder="Password">
                                </div>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                      <div class="log-in-btn margin-top-15 margin-bottom-30" >
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                      </div>
                      </form>
```

I am confused as to what the difference is that would cause this.

Comment: There should be a checkbox in wp admin settings page which says anybody can register. Check it. If it does not solve your probelm, turn on debugging mode by going to wp config and changing debug to true

Comment: @shazyriver this is to my own external database not to WordPress database, doesn't interact with WordPress database other than being on the WordPress based site.

Comment: Anyway you will have to properly debug it. If it is working for login it will for register too.

Comment: @shazyriver any reason you can think of that it would work with one but not the other when they both work outside of WordPress?

Comment: Could be a simple logical or syntax error. Since you are not using wordpress database it should not be specifically related to wordpress.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **plugins_url()**

```
<form action="<?php echo plugins_url( 'form_submit.php', __FILE__ ); ?>" method="post" >
```

Codex Reference https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url.

**Edit:** Please check in wordpress settings. I think you do not have registration enabled.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I had tried this before and it worked with limited success, would this not work properly in a localhost environment? I just plugged this in on one of the two and it works but still is not working for the other which works perfect outside of WP.

Comment: it would work for both localhost and server. Can you explain this in question that in which case it is not working

Comment: Posted more details.